# Codeigniter pagination working but got some issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

Base on the title above, I have a pagination in codeigniter and it displays exactly what I wanted on the first page. But when I click on the 2nd page it displays the same as the first page. Any help will be appreciated.

Model:

```
public function get_users ($limit, $start) {
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$query = $this->db->get ('auth_users');
$result = $query->result ();
  foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
  $data[$key] = array(
      'id'  => $value->id,
      'firstname' => $value->first_name,
      'lastname' => $value->last_name,
      'datereg' => $value->date_registered,
      'email' => $value->email,
      'status' => $value->status ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'
  );
}
return $data;
```

}

Controller:

```
 public function users_page () {
    // Pagination
$config['base_url'] = site_url('main/index');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('auth_users');
$config['per_page'] = 5;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"] = round($choice);

// Config pagination for bootstrap
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;      
$data['users'] = $this->user->get_users($config["per_page"], $page); 
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

// $data['users'] = $this->user->get_users();
$data['title'] = 'Exer-Claide | Members area';

$this->load->view('fragments/header', $data);
$this->load->view('fragments/footer');
$this->load->view ('user_page' , $data);
```

}

Comment: what are you seeing in the url?? last parameter..

Comment: 'index' and when hover to next page it changes to index?page=2

Comment: echo `$page` and check what its giving...

Comment: It only gives 0 number.

Comment: you are using get method??

Comment: try this code,`$p = $_GET['page'];$page = ($p) ? $p : 0;`

Comment: What do u mean by get method? are you referring to a form? I didn't use a form and where should I insert that line of code? in controller where segment located? Thanks

Comment: replace `$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;` with that

Comment: Worked! but the first page gives error. It says undefined index page

Comment: check the answer, i have included there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

replace

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

to

```
$p = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
$page = ($p) ? $p : 0;
```

Comment: How about limiting pages to display on pagination like only 10? when reach page 6 or higher increment the page numbers?

Comment: Example if i have 100 data then displayed 10 rows per page, my pagination number/pages displays 10. what if i want to display only five then display another 6 to 10 after page five reached.

Comment: Now it's displaying from 1 to 10 isit??

Comment: try line, `$config['num_links'] = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `$this->uri->segment(3)`. For example

```
echo $this->uri->segment(3);
```

It is likely that this will not give the appropriate value. If correct , whenever swiped page should give you another value.

Example:

```
$this->uri->segment(3) = 1
```

Next page

```
$this->uri->segment(3) = 2
```

If not give you different values, change the value.

Example:

```
$this->uri->segment(3) or $this->uri->segment(2)
```

The function $this->uri->segment() return the value of url in determinate position.